# Cannot understand this in-line piece of code in the facebook-sdk for python

Tags: python, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm guessing that this is a short hand form of writing a block of code. Could somebody expand this piece of code to look like a regular function?

```
[some_action(post=post) for post in posts['data']]
```

Also what does post=post do in the expression?

Answer (score 0):

It's a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Long code:

```
result= []
for post in posts['data']:
    value= some_action(post=post)
    result.append(value)
```

Comment: Give reference to Python 3, because it should be the future.

Comment: what does post=post do?

Comment: @Betelguese: [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments). It assigns the value of the variable `post` to `some_action`'s parameter named `post`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(some_action, posts):
  res = []
  for post in posts['data']:
    res.append(some_action(post=post))
  return res
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[some_action(post=post) for post in posts['data']]
```

This is a short hand representation of a long function in which some_action is a function which accepts an argument, the first post is the argument and second post sets up the internal parameter for the function some_action, which actually is an event if you look at it closely.

suppose the some_action is a simple print function this would be written in this way in long hand

```
for post in posts['data']:
 print_post(post=post)
```

This will assign the each value of post in posts to an internal parameter named post.